# How to connect Twilio with Wordpress to send app link on desktop website

Tags: php, wordpress, twilio

Do you know how to connect my Twilio account to a form on my website ?
I would like to send text messages to user who visit our website on desktop and fill the form "text me the app link"

I tried to follow these steps https://www.twilio.com/blog/2012/11/increase-app-downloads-with-mobile-app-distribution-powered-by-twilio.html

But I'm blocked at the first step. I created the form, but when I add JavaScript to my website, this one is blocked by chrome because it's not secure ??

And I would like help for next steps too if it's possible, I have no idea on how to modify or create a php file.

I'm on WordPress

Here the JavaScript code added in  head of my website ( thru Divi Builder ):

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[///////////Javascript
$(function(){
$("#frm").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.post("sendnotifications.php", $("#frm").serialize(),
function(data){
if(data.sms_sent == 'OK'){
alert("Message Sent");
} else {
alert("Message Not Sent");
}
}, "json");
});

});
// ]]>
</script>
```

And here is the HTML on my test page
[Test page with HTML code for form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoQgY.png)

Comment: can you show us some code? What error you are receiving when its blocked?

Comment: I edited the post with more informations. 
For the error it's just a chrome warning saying "this website is not secure dont give them your informations..." next to "https" and only when I add the JavaScript code

Comment: try replacing http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js with `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`?

Comment: Nice thanks, first step done, 4 more left :D

Comment: Is it normal that I have no return alert at this stage when I submit the form ? Because I didn't configure PHP yet ?

Comment: I would configure PHP and read the doc carefully. If you have a different issue then ask/open another question. I've provided an answer for your original query. Please accept if it answers your original query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to call a HTTP URL when you are on a HTTPS version of the site. Update your ajax call to use `https`.

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`

To

`https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`

Or you could just use  `//`. This will result in the browser calling whatever protocol the domain is on. i.e. `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js`